# Android ListView position of items

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I want to create ListView where items would have position like on screenshot. So text would be on left side and Switch on right. I know it should be done by TableLayout but I can't figure it out. Thanks for all help.
[image]

Comment: http://www.journaldev.com/10416/android-listview-with-custom-adapter-example-tutorial   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8166497/custom-adapter-for-list-view

Answer (score 2):

You can easily achieve this using `SwitchPreference`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="key_data_saver"
        android:title="Data Saver"
        android:summary="Enable click-to-download for images and videos when using mobile data" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Here is an useful Tutorial: [Android Implementing Preferences Settings Screen](http://www.androidhive.info/2017/07/android-implementing-preferences-settings-screen/)

**OR,**

If you want to create your own without `SwicthPreference`, then use `RecyclerView` with `custom layout` for each `row` item.

**Here is your expected row item layout XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp">

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/switchRight"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:checked="true"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/switchRight"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textTitle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="Data Saver"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="2dp"
            android:textColor="#727272"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Enable click-to-download for images and videos when using mobile data"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Hope this will help~

Answer (score 0):

The best way to implement this is with a PreferenceFragment.

You can create a XML file with all the Settings. (Let's say "settings.xml" inside the folder "XML" that you can create inside "res")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/settings_category_app">
    <SwitchPreference
        android:defaultValue="false"
        android:key="@string/settings_notification_switch"
        android:summary="Enable Click to download images and videos..."
        android:title="Data Saver" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

**Update** it is a static class because I created inside the main activity

After that you can add this resource to your SettingsFragment with:

```
public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings);
    }
}
```

Then you can use this fragment as any other one. (e.g. On a drawer)

Answer (score 0):

TableLayout doesn't need in ur case, cause u don't have any tables. You have to use RelativeLayout instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout 
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:height="wrap_content"
        android:width="match_parent"
        >
        <TextView
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvTitle"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text="Title"
         />
         <TextView
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tvSubTitle"
            android:layout_below="@id/tvTitle"
            android:text="Subtitle"
         />
         <ToggleButton
            android:height="wrap_content"
            android:width="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tbSwitch"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="switch"
         />
    />
```

For IOS styling of ToggleButton u may to use this library: https://github.com/kyleduo/SwitchButton